# uniquely identify html id

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id=Apple1>
    <div id=Round></div>
</div>
<div id=Apple2>
    <div id=Round></div>
</div>
<div id=Apple3>
    <div id=Round></div>
</div>
<div id=Apple4>
    <div id=Round></div>
</div>
<div id=Apple5>
    <div id=Round></div>
</div>

$("#Apple1 #Round")
$("#Apple2 #Round")
$("#Apple3 #Round")
```

Basically i have multiple div different wrapper div id and same inner div id.

can i use jquery this way to uniquely identify div tag?

Comment: Id must be unique, you must use class instead.

Comment: You shouldn't, it's not a valid `HTML` to have multiple elements with the same `id`. You should make `Round` a class rather than an `id`. After that, you can simply do `$("#Apple1 .Round")` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` by definition should be already unique, I'll go as far as saying it's invalid to have more than one of the same `id` in a HTML page.

You can use class if you want:

```
<div id="Apple1">
   <div class="Round">
</div>
...
```

Then

```
$('#Apple1 .Round');
//etc
```

Comment: It *is* literally invalid to have more than one element with the same `id`. Markup validators catch such errors, because the restriction has been formally imposed in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but having multiple elements with the same `id` is not valid HTML under any standard.

Answer (score 0):

id must be unique, use a class for "Round" instead, then to target identify the round inside a unique id div.

```
$('#Apple1 .Round')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't repeat ID's in a  page, they must be unique. Switch your repeating ID's to class

```
<div id=Apple1>
     <div class=Round></div>
 </div>
```

Then you do what you were trying originally

```
 $('#Apple1 .Round').doSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

Id must be unique. You must use class instead of your id "round".

```
<div id="Apple1">
    <div class="Round"></div>
</div>
<div id="Apple2">
    <div class="Round"></div>
</div>
<div id="Apple3">
    <div class="Round"></div>
</div>
<div id="Apple4">
    <div class="Round"></div>
</div>
<div id="Apple5">
    <div class="Round"></div>
</div>
```

Than you can query jquery this way:

```
$("#Apple1 .Round")
$("#Apple2 .Round")
$("#Apple3 .Round")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id=Apple1>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id=Apple2>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id=Apple3>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id=Apple4>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id=Apple5>
    <div></div>
</div>

$("#Apple1").children()
$("#Apple2").children()
$("#Apple3").children()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes dude .

You can use this. But ID must be unique. So its better make it class